# Is it possible to natively invoke behavior of -debugQuickLookObject in Xcode via the keyboard?

Tags: xcode, lldb

Xcode 5.1 supports a [new method for debugging](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/CustomClassDisplay_in_QuickLook/Introduction/Introduction.html) that allows developers to implement a custom Quick Look plug-in for objects via `-debugQuickLookObject` .

To invoke this behavior one must set a breakpoint, click on the desired object in the Variables View of Xcode's Debug area, then either tap the spacebar or click the Quick Look icon.

I would like to be able to trigger this same behavior strictly from the keyboard, ideally from the debug console. I am aware of https://github.com/ryanolsonk/LLDB-QuickLook whose behavior is exactly what I'm looking for, but would prefer a native solution.